# why it needs tableView(_:indentationLevelForRowAt:) when Inserting cell into a table view with static cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Background**

The story is come from the second example of the book ***IOS apprentice (Ed. 6 2016)***

A UItableView with two section is created. In storyboard the following content had been designed: section 0 has one row fulfilled with one static cell, section 1 has two row full filled with two static cell.

**What to achieve**

When tap the last row of section 1 (ie, the **dueDate row** in picture A) a new cell with a UIDatePicker will be inserted into the tableView (please see picture B)

**How does the author solve the problem**

A UITableViewCell filled with a UIDatePicker is added in to the **scene dock** in storyBoard (please see picture C), the new tableCell will be added into the table when dueDate row is tapped

Table view with static cells does not have a data source and therefore does not use the function like “cellForRowAt”. In order to insert this cell into the table the following data source functions had been overridden

```
tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) 
tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)
tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)
tableView(_:indentationLevelForRowAt:)
```

**Problem**

the function `tableView(_:indentationLevelForRowAt:)` really confuse me a lot! And here is the full code

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    var newIndexPath = indexPath
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2 {
      newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section)
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAt: newIndexPath)
  }
```

**Question**

What is the meaning of this function? What's the purpose of it? I've read the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614966-tableview), but I didn't get much information.

When the third row/datePicker cell is inserted `(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2)` why the function will indent the first row `newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section)` ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `tableView(_:indentationLevelForRowAt:)` allows you to display the table rows in a hierarchal / tree-view type format. As in:

```
Level 1
  Sub-Level 1a
  Sub-Level 1b
Level 2
  Sub-Level 2a
    Sub-sub-level 2aa
    Sub-sub-level 2ab
etc...
```

Commonly, one might use:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    if let myObj = myData[indexPath.row] as? MyObject {
        return myObj.myIndentLevel
    }
    return 0
}
```

For the example you present, without reading the book...

It would appear the author decided that the new row (`2`) that contains the `UIDatePicker` should have the same **indent level** as the first row (`0`) in the section. If it's *not* the row `2`, then return the default / current indentation level.

Although, the *intent* of

```
var newIndexPath = indexPath
if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2 {
  newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section)
}
return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAt: newIndexPath)
```

might seem a little more obvious / clear with

```
  newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
```

since it is already limiting this to `section == 1`.